# How many times can I guess a number from Sample 1 belongs to Sample 2 before concluding that they are not the same?

Tags: distributions, confidence-interval

First of all, I apologize for my half-forgotten understanding of statistics.  I hope I can accurately describe what kind of test I'm after in a way that doesn't sound confused.

I have one sample and one population.  I would like to know the probability that my sample is part of that population.  But I also want to know what are the maximum number of "guesses" from my sample it will take in order to conclude that it is, or is not a part of that population.  Let's say I'm looking for a 5% confidence that the sample is or is not part of the population.

So basically, I take a number randomly from my sample, and check to see if it exists in the population.  How many times should I guess until I can feel confident that the sample is or is not part of the population?  I have a funny feeling this is a pretty elementary question and I'm just confused by the word problem aspect of it.

Anyway, I know the size of the sample and the size of the population, if that helps.  A mean of the sample & population is meaningless because these numbers are values, they're labels.  I'm certain there's a more correct way to describe this.  But essentially the numbers are like house addresses, so the difference between 1 and 5 compared to 25 and 300 is meaningless.

Thanks for any help.  I suspect this problem is related to statistical process control.  Thanks again.

Comment: This is answerable generically, but to get the actual number you want you'll also need some estimate of how different is the alternative population the sample might have come from.  If you're hypothesising just one point out of population A is not in  population B but the other points all overlap you will need a very large number of draws from your sample (probably more than in the actual sample), whereas if populations A and B have no overlap at all you only need one draw.  So the actual answer will be a function of population size, sample size, and degree of overlap of populations.